# Error when using "ALL" operator when execute query

Tags: postgresql, phalcon

I need to execute following query using phalcon framework:
"SELECT id FROM table GROUP BY id HAVING '31' = ALL(array_agg(status))"
How can I execute this query using phalcon?
When I do following:

```
 Model::query()
   ->columns(['id'])
   ->groupBy('id')
   ->having('31 = ALL(array_agg(status))')
   ->execute();
```

I get this error message:
Syntax error, unexpected token ALL, near to '(array_agg(status)) ', when parsing: SELECT id FROM [SomeNameSpace\Model] GROUP BY [id] HAVING 31 = ALL(array_agg(status))  (137)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure which Postgres functions are supported, but you can try like this:

```
Model::query()
    ->columns([
        'id',
        'ALL(array_agg(status)) AS statusCounter'
    ])
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->having('31 = statusCounter')
    ->execute();
```

Notice that I moved the aggregation functions in the select, rather in `having` clause.

---

**UPDATE:** here is an example of very custom query. Most functions used are not supported and it's sometimes cleaner just to write a simple SQL query and bind the desired Model to it:

```
public static function findNearest($params = null)
{
    // A raw SQL statement
    $sql = '
        SELECT *, 111.045 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(:lat))
         * COS(RADIANS(X(coords)))
         * COS(RADIANS(Y(coords)) - RADIANS(:lng))
         + SIN(RADIANS(:lat))
         * SIN(RADIANS(X(coords)))))
         AS distance_in_km
        FROM object_locations
        ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
        LIMIT 0,5;    
    ';

    // Base model
    $model = new ObjectLocations();

    // Execute the query
    return new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Resultset\Simple(
        null,
        $model,
        $model->getReadConnection()->query($sql, $params)
    );
}

// How to use:
\Models\ObjectLocations::findNearest([
    'lat' => 42.4961756,
    'lng' => 27.471543300000008
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ALL as dialect extension. Check this topic for example https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/16363/where-yearcurrenttimestamp-how-to-do-this